# Cant get Bootstrap modal.js to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

EDIT:  Keep in mind this answer was asked before Bootstrap 2 came out and therefore is relative to the first release

I am trying to dynamically add and show Bootstrap modal windows with AJAX content, but after looking at the documentation for a good hour and a half I dont understand what classes or attributes I need to add to my modal div so they work with the modal API.

Right now I have something like this:

```
var $modalWindow = $('<div />', {
    class: 'modal fade static',
    style: "display: none;",
    text: "Test"
});

$('body').append($modalWindow);

$modalWindow.modal('show');
```

And it doesnt work... Maybe I am being dense, but I cannot find any info on the docs about how to setup my modal window before calling the show method.

Edit: Fixed it, apparently bootstrap-modal.js requires bootstrap-tipsy.js and bootstrap-popover.js, although it is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation. Seriously, Bootstrap has the worst documentation, specially considering how popular it is.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it, apparently bootstrap-modal.js requires bootstrap-tipsy.js and bootstrap-popover.js, although it is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation. Seriously, Bootstrap has the worst documentation, specially considering how popular it is.

EDIT: Before downvoting this answer, consider this was before bootstrap 2, and as another commenter said he had the exact same issue and also solved it by adding tipsy and popover. 
Boostrap 2 is **way better** than its first incarnation, BTW

Comment: Actually, modal does not require twipsy or popover to function properly. I'm using it fine with only including `bootstrap-modal.js`. Something is probably wrong with your modal template.

  Mine looks like this (can't get it formatted):

`<div id="modal-dialog" class="modal hide fade" style="display: none; " >
<div class="modal-header" ><a href="#" class="close" >×</a >
<h3 >Header</h3 ></div >
<div class="modal-body" >
    <p >  Body    </p>
   </div >
   <div class="modal-footer" >
<a href="#" class="btn cancel info">Cancel</a ><a href="#" class="btn primary" >Save</a ></div ></div >`

Comment: I had similar problem and had the same solution.